# Error while promoting android apps from one track to another using TFS release Google Play - promote task

Tags: android, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[image]We are in process of automating our android app releases using TFS release definitions, we are unable to proceed as the Google play - Promote task fails when promoting the app from Internal test to beta track.

Logs:

2018-05-30T08:52:56.3968703Z ##[section]Starting: Promote Company app to Beta
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3973547Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3973821Z Task         : Google Play - Promote
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3974042Z Description  : Promote an app from one release track to another
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3974263Z Version      : 2.135.0
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3974451Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3974645Z Help         :
2018-05-30T08:52:56.3974852Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-30T08:52:57.1629965Z 6e783899-b52e-421e-a965-71a07243996a exists true
2018-05-30T08:52:57.1787632Z Authenticating with Google Play
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3281897Z Getting information for track internal
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3328244Z { Error: Missing required parameters: editId
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3328709Z     at createAPIRequest (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\googleapis\lib\apirequest.js:109:14)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3330082Z     at Object.get (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\googleapis\apis\androidpublisher\v2.js:1133:16)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3389969Z ##[error]Failed to promote APK.
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3401865Z     at Object.tryCatcher (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3402370Z     at Object.ret [as getAsync] (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promisify.js:163:12), :13:39)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3403181Z     at getTrack (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\google-play-promote.js:112:25)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3403680Z     at D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\google-play-promote.js:53:20
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3404270Z     at tryCatcher (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3404726Z     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:510:31)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3405176Z     at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:584:18)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3405525Z     at Async._drainQueue (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:128:12)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3405915Z     at Async._drainQueues (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3406289Z     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3406619Z     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3406823Z     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3407049Z     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3407219Z   cause:
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3407400Z    Error: Missing required parameters: editId
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3407668Z        at createAPIRequest (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\googleapis\lib\apirequest.js:109:14)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3408026Z        at Object.get (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\googleapis\apis\androidpublisher\v2.js:1133:16)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3408428Z        at Object.tryCatcher (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3408844Z        at Object.ret [as getAsync] (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promisify.js:163:12), :13:39)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3411121Z        at getTrack (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\google-play-promote.js:112:25)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3411753Z        at D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\google-play-promote.js:53:20
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3412167Z        at tryCatcher (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3412666Z        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:510:31)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3413166Z        at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:584:18)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3413679Z        at Async._drainQueue (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:128:12)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3414154Z        at Async._drainQueues (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3414656Z        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\a_tasks\GooglePlayPromote_4dae1f76-29d3-482f-97d5-e3189a8347c2\2.135.0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3415025Z        at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3415807Z        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3416084Z        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5),
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3416354Z   isOperational: true }
2018-05-30T08:52:57.3422430Z ##[section]Finishing: Promote Company app to Beta

Error details:
Missing required parameters: editId

## [error]Failed to promote APK.

Any inputs to resolve this issue would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error has indicated "Missing required parameters: editId", have you checked that?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT All the required parameters are set for the task in release definition, could you elaborate how to set the editId parameter. Thanks.

Comment: Could you set `system.debug` to `true`, and share detailed build log (do not mix privacy information)? Also, please share your release definition.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Thank you, can I share the information via email?

Comment: Sorry that we can't provide email address due to internal policy. You could mask all your private and company's information here.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT The logs and the task details are added. Could you please help.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Could you please check and give insights to resolve the issue. We are unable to release apps using VSTS release definitions. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by providing the actual package name in the Package Name field (e.g.  com.foo.myapp) of the pipeline task UI. Before this change I had a wildcard match like "**/*.apk" which you might expect to work.

I notice the OP has the same idea in the screenshot.

Not sure what to make of the the error message about the editId being missing. Would make more sense if it said the packageId was missing which is what led me to try swapping out the wildcard for the actual package name.

Looking at the source of the extension editId and packageId are related.

https://github.com/Microsoft/google-play-vsts-extension/search?q=editId+is%3Aclosed&type=Code

This appears to be the google api being used: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref